# jekyll server stops everyday at ~6h33 am

Tags: logging, server, jekyll

How can I find out the reason why this is happening? Is there any log I can access to that will tell me the reason why it Jekyll stopped serving?

Comment: Are you talking about the **development** server started with `jekyll serve` ? Please give more details.

Comment: Why do you want to run your Jekyll server all day? Isn't the idea behind Jekyll that you build once and serve the static stuff? I might be missing something though... Please enlighten me!

Comment: yes I actually use `bundler exec jekyll serve --detach` because otherwise it will give me error I haven't yet solve
I am curious why this is happening because I am monitoring uptime and everyday, it will stop at 6h33 and besides it being curious, I want to find out if this is caused by the server networking problems or jekyll timeout functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll is a static site generator. Rather than dynamically creating pages on the fly, everything is created before hand with `jekyll build`.

Therefore, you don't need to run the `jekyll serve` command, on the server, you should be able to see your static files, e.g. `index.html` without any Jekyll commands.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/27ed81547b12d28a60c51961b82a5723981feb7d/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb#L175), `jekyll serve` simply gives you a temporary server to view your files from. And when we use the `--detach` command we can see that Jekyll simply starts a server in a new thread.

- Try looking at the Jekyll [getting started guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) (past the first page) for details about how to deploy to a server.